# Передача в функцию параметров, если нужно потом вызвать событие e

Tags: javascript

Предположим, что есть функция:

```
showPopup: function($el) {
    $el.addClass("current");
}
```

Необходимо добавить в нее строку:

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

Как добавить событие `e` в параметры этой функции?

Comment: Остановка всплытия может быть вызвана только у объекта события `Event`. Передаётся в обработчик аргументом, IE создаёт объект глобально в `window.event` (хром его тоже поддерживает, но это, скорее, исключение (FF не ставит)). Так что смотреть надо где именно назначается обработчик.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Просто добавить нужный параметр в функцию:

```
showPopup: function(event, $el) {
    event = event || window.event
    $el.addClass("current");
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

[Объект события](https://learn.javascript.ru/obtaining-event-object)

В браузерах, работающих по рекомендациям W3C, объект события всегда передается в обработчик первым параметром. Например:

```
function doSomething(event) {
    // event - будет содержать объект события
}

element.onclick = doSomething;
```

При вызове обработчика объект события event будет передан ему первым аргументом.
Можно назначить и вот так:

```
element.onclick = function(event) {
    // event - объект события
}
```

Интересный побочный эффект - в возможности использования переменной event при назначении обработчика в HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="alert(event)" value="Жми сюда не ошибешься"/>
```

Это работает благодаря тому, что браузер автоматически создает функцию-обработчик с данным телом, в которой первый аргумент event.

В Internet Explorer существует глобальный объект window.event, который хранит в себе информацию о последнем событии. А первого аргумента обработчика просто нет.

То есть, все должно работать так:

```
// обработчик без аргументов
function doSomething() {
    // window.event - объект события
}

element.onclick = doSomething;
```

Обратите внимание, что доступ к event при назначении обработчика в HTML по-прежнему будет работать. Такой вот надежный и простой кросс-браузерный доступ к объекту события.